# How to take screenshot in HTC Wildfire S A510e mobile?

Tags: android, screen

Here, I am running my android application in my HTC Wildfire S A510e mobile, But, I don't have any idea, on how to take screenshots of my app. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Look at this . http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-take-screenshots-of-android-device/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the DDMS perspective in eclipse you can find a camera icon. By clicking on it you take the screenshot of the current screen of your phone.